# Word count issue with JS

Tags: javascript, html, word-count

I am very, very new at JS with no programming experience and I am struggling with creating a script that counts words in a text box. I have the following code and I can't get anything to populate:

```
    var myTextareaElement = document.getElementById("myWordsToCount");
    myTextareaElement.onkeyup = function(){
      var wordsCounted = myTextareaElement.value;
      var i = 0;
      var str = wordsCounted; 
      var words = str.split('');
      for (var i = words.length; i++) {if (words[i].length > 0; i++) { words[i]  };
}
```

And for the Span Id in my HTML, I put the following:

```
<span id="wordsCounted"></span>
```

Any direction I where I am royally messing up would be great. I have tried it in JS fiddle and can't get it to populate.

Comment: Try instead of using str.split("") which is spiting every character, split ever white space. str.split(" ");

Comment: it looks like you don't have a space in str.split(''), try str.split(' ')

Comment: Do you want to count the words or want to show how many words are remaining?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't get anything to populate"? What exactly is the issue you are encountering?

Comment: I am trying to count words at every space. I will correct the " "

Comment: this is a pretty good plugin that i have used in the past http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/10/jquery-plugin-word-counter-textarea.html

Answer (score 3):

The split method needs a proper character, you can use an space " " or a regex to indicate any whitespace character: `"My name is   XXX".split(/\s+/)` will show `["My", "name", "is", "XXX"]`.
If you just want the number of words you can do `"My name is   XXX".split(/\s+/).length`, which will return 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this may do what you want. Instead of doing a for loop, just count how many words are there and display the length of the array.

```
var myTextareaElement = document.getElementById("myWordsToCount");
    myTextareaElement.onkeyup = function(){
      var wordsCounted = myTextareaElement.value;
      var i = 0;
      var str = wordsCounted; 
      var words = str.split('');
      if (words.length > 0){
          document.getElementById('wordsCounted').innerHTML = words.length;
      }
}
```